# Can I see an example .pro for qt that integrates opencv as well?

Tags: xcode, image, qt, image-processing, opencv

I hm having a hard time integrating opencv with qt on xcode. If anyone has an example of working copy that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example which works great with a classic installation of OpenCV (apt-get or opencv wiki install) on Linux / Mac.

> TEMPLATE          =   app
>   TARGET                =   BIN/appName
>
> QT                +=      core \
>                         xml
>
> INCLUDEPATH           +=  INC/folder/ \
>                         INC/otherFoled/
>
> HEADERS           +=  INC/folder/*.h \
>                     INC/otherFoled/*.h
>
> SOURCES                   +=  SRC-BIN/main.cpp
>
> SOURCES                   +=  SRC-LIB/folder/*.cpp
>   MOC_DIR                   +=  LIB/
>   OBJECTS_DIR               +=  OBJ/
>
> CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
>   PKGCONFIG += opencv

Good luck !